# Find columns with given names and move those columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I wrote VBA code based code which does a similar procedure.
The idea is to find the columns with the given names and move those columns to column X and after (whatever column amount needed).

The code only performs with the column "Job Function". It puts it in column W. The rest of the columns are not cut and paste.

```vb
Sub SortColumns2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim colJobfunction As Range
    Dim colManagementLevel As Range
    Dim colCompanyDivisionName As Range
    Dim colDepartment As Range
    Dim colContactAccuracyScore As Range
    Dim colContactAccuracyGrade As Range
    Dim colLinkedIn As Range
    Dim columnHeader As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    
    ' Find the wanted columns to be sorted
    For Each rng In ws.Rows(1).Cells
        columnHeader = Trim(CStr(rng.Value))
        
        Select Case columnHeader
            Case "Job Function"
                Set colJobfunction = rng
            Case "Management Level"
                Set colManagementLevel = rng
            Case "Company Division Name"
                Set colCompanyDivisionName = rng
            Case "Department"
                Set colDepartment = rng
            Case "Contact Accuracy Score"
                Set colContactAccuracyScore = rng
            Case "Contact Accuracy Grade"
                Set colContactAccuracyGrade = rng
        End Select
    Next rng
        
    ' Move the found columns to Range X
    If Not colJobfunction Is Nothing Then
        colJobfunction.EntireColumn.Cut
        ws.Columns("X").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    ElseIf Not colManagementLevel Is Nothing Then
        colManagementLevel.EntireColumn.Cut
        ws.Columns("X").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    ElseIf Not colCompanyDivisionName Is Nothing Then
        colCompanyDivisionName.EntireColumn.Cut
        ws.Columns("X").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    ElseIf Not colDepartment Is Nothing Then
        colDepartment.EntireColumn.Cut
        ws.Columns("X").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    ElseIf Not colContactAccuracyScore Is Nothing Then
        colContactAccuracyScore.Insert.Cut
        ws.Columns("X").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    ElseIf Not colContactAccuracyGrade Is Nothing Then
        colContactAccuracyGrade.Insert.Cut
        ws.Columns("X").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If ... then ... elseif etc. means that only one of these things will happen. I presume you wanted them all to happen, so use If ... then ... end if for each column title

Comment: `colJobfunction` will always be "something" once the corresponding header has been found. Honestly I think this  could be simplified a lot.

Comment: BigBen, can you make some suggestions?
Are you thinking of an approach using an Array?

Or are you thinking that the Inserting cutting of columns should be done within the Select Case

Comment: Found an issue with the previously posted, now deleted answer. Does your spreadsheet have columns populated to the right of column X?

Comment: I was wondering why you deleted the answer.. I was also thinking, wouldn't you want the columns in a certain order, i.e. Job Function first -> Management Level, etc. or is that already in that order in the sheet?

Comment: @BigBen yes it does.
In fact ideally, I would like to move the columns to the right a another column named "LinkedInProfile__c" or "LinkedIn Contact Profile URL".

Answer (score 2):

you could try this code (make a backup copy of your sheet before!)

```
Option Explicit

Sub SortThoseDamnedColumns()
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mySheetName") '<-- change "mySheetName" to your actual sheet name
        
        Dim colsRng As Range, _
            rng As Range, _
            startingColRng As Range
            
            For Each rng In .Range(.Range("A1"), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
                Select Case Trim(CStr(rng.Value))
                    Case "Job Function", "Management Level", "Company Division Name", _
                         "Department", "Contact Accuracy Score", "Contact Accuracy Grade"
                        If colsRng Is Nothing Then
                            Set colsRng = rng
                        Else
                            Set colsRng = Union(colsRng, rng)
                        End If

                    Case "LinkedInProfile__c", "LinkedIn Contact Profile URL"
                        Set startingColRng = rng.Offset(, 1)
                End Select
            Next
            
                If Not colsRng Is Nothing And Not startingColRng Is Nothing Then
                    With colsRng
                        .EntireColumn.Copy startingColRng
                        .EntireColumn.Delete
                    End With
                End If
                    
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello there
Thanks for providing the code.
So unfortunately, it runs but nothing happens.
Or if anything happens its not with the columns that need to be moved.

Comment: Oh I found what happened.
I stored the VBA macros into the Personal.XLSB workbook.
It seems when I run it from there to operating on the other open sheet I have active, its not working on the correct sheet.

The way I defined the sheet was

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

But maybe I should not use ThisWorkbook ?

Comment: So now when I run the code I get an error: "The operation cannot be completed for one of the following reasons: 
- A selection including cells both inside a table and below it cannot be copied and inserted into that table. Select cells outside the table and try inserting the data again
- You have attempted to fill data in a way not supported by the table.

When I click debug it points me to the line
.EntireColumn.Copy startingColRng

Comment: @AlexandreBrandt, yes, omit "ThisWorkbook" if you have to act on the currently active sheet in whatever workbook it is

Comment: @AlexandreBrandt, so your columns to be shifted are part of a table object? You didn't specify that in the OP

Comment: Hello. Sorry for the delayed reply. 
I guess those columns are part of the table object yes. This operation i’m doing will only happen on tables. I can see that the current VBA script does refer to any table object.

Answer (score 1):

### Sort Columns in an Excel Table According to a List

[image]

- This moves entire (worksheet) columns so cells above and below the table will also move.
- There is of course a way to keep it inside the table's rows which should be explored.

```vb
Sub SortTableColumns()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const TABLE_ID As Variant = 1 ' ?
    Dim sHeaders(): sHeaders = Array( _
        "Job Function", _
        "Management Level", _
        "Company Division Name", _
        "Department", _
        "Contact Accuracy Score", _
        "Contact Accuracy Grade")
    Dim dHeaders(): dHeaders = Array( _
        "LinkedInProfile__c", _
        "LinkedIn Contact Profile URL")
    
    ' Reference the table.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' improve!
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = ws.ListObjects(TABLE_ID)
    
    Dim dlc As ListColumn, dHeader As Variant
    
    ' Determine the name of the destination column.
    For Each dHeader In dHeaders
        On Error Resume Next
            Set dlc = lo.ListColumns(dHeader)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not dlc Is Nothing Then Exit For
    Next dHeader
    
    ' Check if no destination header found.
    If IsEmpty(dHeader) Then
        MsgBox "None of the listed headers found: " & vbLf & vbLf _
            & Join(dHeaders, vbLf), vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Define an array to store the initial column widths.
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = lo.ListColumns.Count
    Dim ColWidths(): ReDim ColWidths(1 To cCount, 1 To 2)
    
    Dim c As Long
    
    ' Store all column names and widths in the array.
    For c = 1 To cCount
        ColWidths(c, 1) = lo.ListColumns(c).Name
        ColWidths(c, 2) = lo.ListColumns(c).Range.ColumnWidth
    Next c
    
    Dim slc As ListColumn, scrg As Range, dcrg As Range, sHeader As Variant
    Dim dcOffset As Long, IsFirstFound As Boolean
    
    ' Move columns.
    For Each sHeader In sHeaders
        On Error Resume Next
            Set slc = lo.ListColumns(sHeader)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not slc Is Nothing Then
            Set scrg = slc.Range.EntireColumn
            dcOffset = dcOffset + 1
            Set dcrg = dlc.Range.EntireColumn.Offset(, dcOffset)
            If scrg.Column <> dcrg.Column Then
                If Not IsFirstFound Then IsFirstFound = True
                scrg.Cut
                dcrg.Insert Shift:=xlShiftToRight
            End If
            Set slc = Nothing
        End If
    Next sHeader
    
    ' Check if no columns moved.
    If Not IsFirstFound Then
        MsgBox "The columns had already been sorted.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Apply the initial column widths.
    For c = 1 To cCount
        lo.ListColumns(ColWidths(c, 1)).Range.ColumnWidth = ColWidths(c, 2)
    Next c
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Columns sorted.", vbInformation

End Sub
```